# Filter postgres JSON column by null value in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

So I've got a model like such:

```
class myModel(Base):

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    border = Column(JSONB)
```

How can I query for rows that don't have a border? I've tried:

```
filter(myModel.border != None) #nope
filter(myModel.border != 'null') #nope
from sqlalchemy import null
filter(myModel.border != null()) #nope
```

The value is apparently stored in `postgres` as a ["JSON encoded null value"](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issue/3159/cant-insert-null-into-a-json-column-if). Its definitely getting serialized back to a python `None` when instantiated, but I have no idea how to query against it. It looks like you can set `none_as_null` on the column, i.e.:

```
Column(JSONB(none_as_null=True))
```

Which replaces the JSON encoded `null` with a SQL null, but that seems strange to have to do on all columns. What am I missing here?

edit: should mention this is v0.9.8 of sqlalchemy

Answer (score 4):

This works for both `border` as JSON `null` and PostgresQL `NULL`:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import text
filter(myModel.border != text("'null'"))
```

(tested with `SQLAlchemy==1.1.14`)

Comment: Doesn't work for me with PostgreSQL 9.6 and SQLAlchemy 1.1.x or 1.2.x. It's throwing this error

```ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: json <> unknown
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.```

I had success importing null from sqlalchemy and comparing with `null()`

Answer (score 4):

from sqlalchemy>=0.7.9, you could use the filter operator `.isnot` instead of comparing constraints like this - `filter(myModel.border.isnot(None))`

To get models with border nulls, do `filter(myModel.border.is_(None))`

Comment: This one only works when the model specifies `JSONB(none_as_null=True)` or `JSON(none_as_null=True)`. See [JSON.none_as_null](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.JSON.params.none_as_null)

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL has function **jsonb_typeof**, that returns string type of json value. So you can filter null values as `jsonb_typeof(myModel.border) != 'null'`.
You can find details in the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`JSON.NULL`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.JSON.NULL). From the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.JSON):

> To insert or select against a value that is SQL NULL, use the constant `null()`:
>
> ```
> from sqlalchemy import null
> conn.execute(table.insert(), json_value=null())
> ```
>
> To insert or select against a value that is JSON `"null"`, use the constant `JSON.NULL`:
>
> ```
> conn.execute(table.insert(), json_value=JSON.NULL)
> ```

So in your case,

```
from sqlalchemy import JSON

myModel.query.filter(myModel.border != JSON.NULL)
```

Answer (score -1):

```python
from sqlalchemy import null

#If you try to insert data in db:  
YourModel(my_json_column = null())

#get data by filter: 
select(Table).where(Table.my_json_column.is_(None))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question will make it more useful for others in the future. Please consider updating your answer with some explanatory notes. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

you will be able to persist this using the value null()

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import null

>>> filter(myModel.border != null())
```

Comment: It works for me with SQLAlchemy 1.1 or 1.2 and PostgreSQL 9.6 using the type sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSON
While it doesn't work the suggestion of using the comparison with `text("'null'")`.